# Flutter test access the state of a found widget

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I have a Flutter widget that I would like to test

```
                Step(
                  title: const Text('Initialize a New Flutter Release'),
                  content: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ConductorSubsteps(continued: continued),
                    ],
                  ),
                  isActive: true,
                  state: handlerStepState(0),
                ),
```

I would like to check if `isActive` of this widget is true. How should I do that?

I tried `expect(find.text('Continue').isActive, equals(true));` This does not work, since I can't call `.isActive` on an iterator.
`expect(tester.element(find.text('Continue').isActive, equals(true)));` does not work, since `.isActive` can't be called on an element.

Answer (score 0):

Try `expect(tester.widget<Step>(find.text('Continue').first).isActive, isTrue);`

This assumes the widget found with `find.text` is a `Step` widget.

Comment: I just tried your solution. <Step> is underlined in red with an error of ```'Step' doesn't conform to the bound 'Widget' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Widget'.darttype_argument_not_matching_bounds
class Step
package:flutter/src/material/stepper.dart

```

Comment: The snippet does indeed expect that Step is a Widget, which is also what you said at the start of your question